# In R plotly d3js how to format a number with space instead of comma?

Tags: r, d3.js, plotly

I am working with R plotly which is based on d3js, and would like to format axis ticks. I saw I have to use the "tickformat" option in layout, which has to be set using the syntax described here : https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format but I can't get to change the grouping symbol (the thousand separator) : it's a comma and would like it to be a space.

By default, I get number formatted like this :

```
1500
```

I can get them formatted like this :

```
1,500
```

by using tickformat=",", but I would like to format like that :

```
1 500
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you talking about the *thousands* separator? You want it to be a space instead of a comma, is that correct?

Comment: @Gerardo yes that's it. Sorry for not being clear, I will try to edit my initial demand.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but still answering in case other people could benefit from it.

You can use the comma as thousand separator and add the locale in your graph.

For example in Python, if you would like to have an Indicator that displays the number with a space as thousand separator, you could do the following:

```
go.Indicator(
 mode = "number",
 value = num_value,
 number = {
  'font.size': 45,
  "valueformat": ","
},
```

And in the Graph object, you can add the following:

```
dcc.Graph(id="something", config=dict(locale="fr")
```